# Prove that $a^2 pq + b^2 qr + c^2 rp \leq $ given a,b and c are sides of triangle and p+q+r=0

Tags: inequality, contest-math

The question is asking to prove that $a^2 pq + b^2 qr + c^2 rp  \leq 0 $ given that $a,b$ and $c$ are the sides of a triangle and that $p+q+r=0$.

I have tried AM GM as well as countless pages of algebra however I can't seem to prove this one. This question is actually found on the beginning pages of an inequality book so not many known inequalities are known to the reader at this point (not even AM GM has been developed yet!!) so if you can solve it using simple inequality techniques it would be better but if that can't be the case then I'll do the research on the methods employed. This question was also in a past tournament of towns paper but I can't find the solution.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all p, q , r cant be positive or negative .WLOG, we assume $ p,q\geq0 $ and $r = -(p+q)$.
So we have to prove $$a^2pq\leq (p+q)(b^2q + c^2p)$$.
Dividing by pq,$$a^2\leq (p+q)(b^2/p + c^2/q)$$.(Work it out if one of them is 0).
Expand right hand side to 
$$b^2 + c^2 + b^2q/p + c^2p/q$$.
Applying AM-GM to the 2 right most terms, 
$$b^2q/p + c^2p/q\geq 2bc$$.
Which implies ,
$$a^2\leq(b+c)^2\leq b^2 + c^2 + b^2q/p + c^2p/q$$.

Comment: This is good man thanks a lot!! I like that initial condition that p,q≥0 because we can choose any 2 of the 3 so it can be easily generalized and if p and q were to be negative it would work much the same way.

Comment: May I ask, how did you come up with this idea? A lot of experience teaches you these tricks?

Comment: @TushantMittal,  It could happen that exactly one of p, q, r is positive

Comment: @Cupid,If one of them is positive say,r, then take their negatives i.e (-p),(-q),(-r).Now these satisfy the equation and the inequality stays intact.

Comment: @Pablo.I am glad I could help.I am not sure how I got the idea.I definitely do not have a lot of experience regarding inequalities barring a little involving AM-GM.I think that the first step simplified the problem a lot and it was trivial from there on.